# how to create an array of objects with increasing size?

Tags: inkscape

I would like to create a 2-D array of objects with size and horizontal separation increasing like this:

```
[[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
[ 5,  6,  7,  8],
[ 9, 10, 11, 12],
[13, 14, 15, 16]]
```

with the clone tile, I can only achieve the size increasing with a parameter row (400%), col (100%). However, I cannot find out how to increase the separation like this.

Answer (score 0):

Cumulate creates the sort of progression you want along y. But I am not sure to interpret correctly what you want, so giving an example for the 4 top left objects would be good.